# Django passes known an exact string as a url parameter

Tags: python, django, path, django-urls, path-converters

I have two urls in dispatcher pointing the same view:

```
path('posts/top/', posts, name='top'),
path('posts/new/', posts, name='new'),
```

I want view start as follows:

```
def posts(request, ordering):
    ...
```

I guess, to pass `top` and `new` as a parameter it should be something like:

```
path('posts/<ordering:top>/', posts, name='top'),
path('posts/<ordering:new>/', posts, name='new'),
```

But it gives me:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: URL route 'posts/<ordering:top>/' uses invalid converter 'ordering'.
```

So, as a work around I use this, but it looks a little bit dirty:

```
path('posts/top/', posts, name='top', kwargs={'order': 'top'}),
path('posts/new/', posts, name='new', kwargs={'order': 'new'}),
```

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: What do you want to implement?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You've misunderstood the way path converters work. The first element is the type, which here is `str`, and the second is the parameter name to use when calling the view. At this point you don't constrain the permissible values themselves. So your path would be:

```
path('posts/<str:ordering>/', posts, name='posts')
```

and when you come to reverse you would pass in the relevant parameter:

```
{% url 'posts' ordering='top' %}
```

If you really want to ensure that people can only pass those two values, you can either check it programmatically in the view, or you can use `re_path` to use regex in your path:

```
re_path(r'^posts/(?P<ordering>top|new)/$', posts, name='posts')
```

Comment: Ye, I know, I've made a very simple example, but the real task is incredibly complex, so, I wanted to know everything that is possible about urls in django

Comment: to me it looks like that path segments are called url parameters in django. what do you call actual url parameters? I am looking for relevant info but I can not find useful documentation because of the before mentioned confusion. To be sure I am talking about the url parameters after the question mark "/seg1/seg2/seg3?param1=42&param2=43".

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error below:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: URL route 'test/<id:id>/'
> uses invalid converter 'id'.

Because I use `id` as a converter as shown below:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('test/<id:id>/', views.test, name="test")
]              # ↑ Converter
```

So, I use `int` as a converter as shown below, then the error was solved:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('test/<int:id>/', views.test, name="test")
]              # ↑ Converter
```

In addition, `str`, `int`, `slug`, `uuid` and `path` converters are available by default according to [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters).